# How can I create returns for zero checkout order?

Tags: magento2.4.4, refund, zero-subtotal, returns

I understand that we can not refund for zero subtotal checkout order. But can we create return in case wrong item delivered or item damaged due to delivery?
In my Magento ver 2.4.4, after click Create Returns, there should have been "Submit returns" button next to Cancel button, but it doesn't.
[image: no Submit returns button]

Comment: explain the issue in some more details.